# WebAuthenticationBroker return UserCancel

Tags: c#, authentication, uwp

I try authorize and get authorization code in Microsoft using WebAuthenticationBroker, but it just return UserCancel.

```
        var Result = await WebAuthenticationBroker
                           .AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None,new Uri(url));
```

URL template: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={0}&response_type=id_token+code&redirect_uri={1}&response_mode=form_post&scope={2}&state=12345&nonce=678910";](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=%7B0%7D&response_type=id_token+code&redirect_uri=%7B1%7D&response_mode=form_post&scope=%7B2%7D&state=12345&nonce=678910%22;)

When I try authorize in Google, I get same error.

Comment: It's hard to detect the problem with above description, please refer to [document trouble](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-authentication-broker#debugging) troubleshoot steps and get error log. I will help to check it.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, I get this warning: 
The для конкретного приложения permission settings do not grant Локально Активация permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{2593F8B9-4EAF-457C-B68A-50F6B8EA6B54}
 and APPID 
{15C20B67-12E7-4BB6-92BB-7AFF07997402}
 to the user MyUserName SID (S-1-5-21-959161372-2168236279-2063342856-1002) from address LocalHost (с использованием LRPC) running in the application container Недоступно SID (Недоступно). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: And this error: svchost (26744,R,98) TILEREPOSITORYS-1-5-18: Error -1023 (0xfffffc01) occurred while opening logfile C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer\Database\EDB.log.

Comment: The error looks you have not enable app's permission for `WebAuthenticationBroker`. please check if you have enable internet capability and enterprise authentication.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have this capabilities.
`<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="sharedUserCertificates"/>
    <uap:Capability Name="userAccountInformation"/>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer"/>
  </Capabilities>`

Comment: Have you tested with other machine. and can you check if your client id is available ?

Comment: I try test this code in other app, and get this error after typing email - invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.
I get redirect_uri using `WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri()`

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, When I try tested on other machine I get message - We can't connect to the service you need right now. Check your network connection or try this again later. Its magic, I am puzzled.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot, we suggest you test within web side and confirm your registered  application is available first.